# Cakephp: Is it possible to limit the number of database connections?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, configuration

I read that Bluehost limits the number of database connections from one user to 15. I believe my webapp is using up all those connections. Whenever I try to use the cake console to access the database, I get the following error:

> 2011-11-29 05:06:58 Warning: Warning (2): mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: User
>   myusername already has more than 'max_user_connections' active
>   connections in
>   [/home2/myusername/public_html/myapp/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php,
>   line 561]

How can I make sure there are connections for the cake console to use?

**Edit:**

Just to be clear, my app is not running out of connections.  However, **every time** I try to access the database from the cake console I get that error.  This leads me to believe that cake is creating and holding onto the connections for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't configured a persistent database connection in your app/config/database.php? Cake should close that database connection whenever it's done parsing otherwise. Or are you trying to launch more then 15 requests simultaneously?

Comment: Nope.  Not using persistent connections.  I'll try to replicate the error in development.  var $production = array('driver' => 'mysql', 'persistent' => false, 'host' => 'localhost', 'prefix' => '', ...);

Comment: You can tell this is the limit of the hosting provider: they are not allowing more than 15 requests at the same time. Maybe you can work it around by caching at some level (avoiding to go to the db each time), but this hosting is obviously not meant to scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the root user account (or with super privileges),
you can change cli script to connect using root,
as root connection even the max connection is reached (max + 1)

You can make use of `php_sapi_name` to distinguish between normal web access or via console.

I don't think max connection is capped at 15,
if so you should consider another hosting company other than bluehost (because is suck) ...

To verify this, issue a SQL like :-

```
show variables like "max%";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I used the command you suggested and 'max_user_connections' is indeed 15.  'max_user_connections' limits the number of simultaneous connections that can be made by any given account.  Unfortunately, I'm a third party developer for this website so I have to deal with bluehost.

Comment: mysqld actually permits max_connections+1 clients to connect. The extra connection is reserved for use by accounts that have the SUPER privilege.

Comment: The app is using the database provided by bluehost.  I do not (and shouldn't) have super access.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: No, you don't ... there is nothing can be done ... contact bluehost